# SnapshotListener not working offline when querying by server timestamp

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

In my chat app, I retrieve new chat messages via this query:

```kotlin
fun getNewChatMessages(chat: Chat, from: Date) =
    getCollectionForChat(chat)
        .document(chat.documentId!!)
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy("timeStamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("timeStamp", from)
        .addSnapshotListener( [...]
```

The "timestamp" field is a server timestamp:

```kotlin
data class ChatMessage(
    val text: String? = null,
    val senderUid: String? = null,
    val senderName: String? = null,
    val imageUrl: String? = null,

    @ServerTimestamp val timeStamp: Date? = null,
    @DocumentId val documentId: String? = null
)
```

When I add a new chat message to the collection while offline, I am not getting any live updates. I could track the problem down to this line of the query:

```kotlin
.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("timeStamp", from)
```

Without this line, I get updates immediately even while offline.
Does equality queries on the server timestamp only work once the data is persisted on the server? If yes, what is my alternative? Using a local timestamp (i.e. `Date()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()`)?

Comment: How do you define the timestamp? With FieldValue?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes, I forgot to mention that properly. I updated the question, thank you.